# Javascript map not working with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to parse some markdown, and so that involves going through a string and changing markdown style links into `<a>` tags.

```js
// Grab markdown links
const links = markdown.match(/\[.*?\]\(.*?\)/g);
            
const parsed_links = links.map(x => {
    `<a href='${x.match(/\(.*?\)/)[0]}'></a>`
});
```

The first part, getting `links`, is confirmed to work, but the mapping is not working at all; returning `[undefined, undefined]`. Especially frustrating is that the line `console.log(links[0].match(/\(.*?\)/)[0]);` works as expected, but just not in the map. At this point I'm just trying to grab the bit in the brackets, the URL.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are not returning anything from the map function.

If you use curly brackets in arrow function, you must use `return`

```
const parsed_links = links.map(x => {
  return `<a href='${x.match(/\(.*?\)/)[0]}'></a>`
});
```

Only if you don't use curly brackets you don't need the `return`:

```
const parsed_links = links.map(x => `<a href='${x.match(/\(.*?\)/)[0]}'></a>`);
```